# Where's my backslash gone?

Tags: characters

When I try to use one of the more "hacky" methods of getting a literal "special character" (such as backslash or a brace) then I get a different character: backslash seems to be an open quote, left brace a dash, and right brace a close quote.  What happened to my special characters?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

\char`\\
\char`\{
\char`\}

\end{document}
```

produces: `"-"` (only the two `"`s are different).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your special characters are in the wrong font table that is loaded by default! Printing them using a different character set will bring them back!

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
  \texttt{\char`\\}\\
  \texttt{\char`\{}\\
  \texttt{\char`\}}\\
\end{document}
```

See [Why do lower case mathcal letters show up as random symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/why-do-lower-case-mathcal-letters-show-up-as-random-symbols) for some help as to how to print a font table.

Answer (score 9):

As Yiannis wrote, it's the font table. However, using `fontenc`, you can get them to show up as you want.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\char`\\
\char`\{
\char`\}
\end{document}
```